# Clang-tidy problem encountered with multiple architectures

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-tidy

I'm working on creating a custom clang-tidy checker for a large codebase. To run my clang-tidy checker, I need to generate a compile_commands.json database for all files. The problem I'm facing is that this is a multi architecture project, so most of the files are compiled with two architecture flags, in this case, as extracted from compile_commands.json

> -arch x86_64 -arch arm64

Unfortunately I don't think clang-tidy is capable of operating with multiple architectures because I get this error at every file checked:

> 13:40:08  [0;1;31merror: [0m[1munable to handle compilation,
> expected exactly one compiler job in '

I found a similar issue resolved for clangd (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/3bf77980d934c4aa383e4ea9a9a5de86598bea9b), but I couldn't find how I can bypass this issue except for modifying the codebase, which I do not want.

Comment: Why don't you just call clang-tidy twice? and pass in the relevant arch type to each

Comment: @user20716902 is there a way to pass the architecture to clang-tidy? I couldn't find any

Comment: In the end, I just commented the piece of code where llvm checks for multiple architectures and throws this error. In my case I've seen that the checker is not affected but I don't know what problems can occur for other checkers with that error disabled

`// if (CC1Jobs.empty() || (CC1Jobs.size() > 1 && !ignoreExtraCC1Commands(Compilation))) {`